# AJAX function doesn't send data to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a submit form and I don't want that after submit, the page refresh, so I created an AJAX function that should send data to a PHP file but the problem is that the AJAX function doesn't send variables to PHP script.

index.html with the form

```
<!-- FORM -->
<form name="form" id="form" method="post">
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- GAME -->
<select class="form-control" id="game-group" name="game" onchange="ChangeBackground();">
<option selected disabled>Select your Game...</option>
<option value="League_of_Legends">League of Legends</option>
<option value="Heartstone">Hearthstone</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- QUESTION -->
<div class="input-group" id="question-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Start typing your question...">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<!-- OPTIONS -->
<div class="form-group form-group-options col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="input-group input-group-option col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="options-group">
<input type="text" name="option[]" id="option" class="form-control" placeholder="Options...">
<span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- CHOICE -->
<div class="checkbox" id="choice-group">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="choice" name="choice" value="Yes">Allow multiple choice
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" onclick="sendForm()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Poll</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

magic.js with AJAX function

```
function sendForm()
{
var form = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
form.append('view_type','addtemplate');
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:  function(data)
    {
        alert("GeGe");
    }
});
}
```

process.php (in the query I only insert into database one variable to see if it works, don't worry about this)

```
<?php

//Include configuration file
include('includes/config.php');

//Define variables
$game=$_POST['game'];
$question=$_POST['question'];
$option=$_POST['option'];
$choice=$_POST['choice'];

//Generate random number
$rand_value=rand();

//Create temporary folder
//mkdir($rand_value);

//Copy page of Ask Poll
//copy('page.php', $rand_value . '/page.php');
//rename($rand_value . '/page.php', $rand_value . '/index.php');

//Add data into database
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("Errore di connessione!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Impossibile selezionare database!");
//$sql1="CREATE TABLE `" . $rand_value . "` (Question VARCHAR(200), Options VARCHAR(200), Choice INT(11))";
//mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Impossibile eseguire la query!");

$sql2="INSERT INTO `675197851` (Question) VALUES ($question)";
mysql_query($sql2);
//Count number of Options available
//$count=count($option);

//for ($i=0; $i<($count-1); $i++)
//{
//  ${$sql . $i}="INSERT INTO `" . $rand_value . "` (Question, Options, Choice) VALUES ($question2, $option2[$i], $choice2)";
//  mysql_query(${$sql . $i});
//} 
?>
```

Comment: something goes wrong" isn't clear enough. Can you add more details on what is expected and the current result, or the error you get

Comment: add `return false;` to the end of your `sendForm` function

Comment: /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var form = $("#form").serialize();

Comment: 1. Does the AJAX function even run?
2. If the AJAX function does run what is the response?
3. Is error reporting ON on your PHP page and does it show any errors?
4. IS the URL correct?
5. Mysql is now depreciated use Mysql_ or PDO :-)

Comment: It runs because i see the popup with the text "GeGe" as you can see in the script. How can I see the response?

Comment: @Cricco — Look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: `$question` is most likely to be a string, so you need to quote it `'$question'` or `'".$question."'` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score -1):

if your are using JQuery then try this kind of solution.

```
function sendForm()
{
    $.post( "process.php", $( "#form" ).serialize())
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
}
```

Comment: I tryed but it doesn't work, in fact the popup is Data Loaded: only with nothing else

Comment: Then you have problems in your php script. Besides "echo" something in the php script to get the value in js popup.